# Are there downsides to writing PDO/mysqli statements into my code directly vs using my own redirect wrapper methods?

Tags: php, database, refactoring, maintenance, side-effect

TL;DR:  To access DB functionality in my codebase I currently use a custom layer throughout the code.  The layer needs an upgrade in order to begin accepting prepared statements, which it currently does not.  I have a choice between abandoning using the custom layer in favor of using another layer directly instead - such as PDO/mysqli, or to keep using my layer as is, but amend it to accept prepared statements (as much as it will allow via making any necessary adjustments to the constructs encapsulated inside the layer itself (in my case using myslqi/PDO behind my layer, to avoid having to rewrite every single call to the layer throughout my code)

---

I currently have `mysqli` extensions in my PHP codebase.  Also, in my codebase I do not use prepared statements.  My calls to DB are wrapped into proprietary method calls that are really just redirects to `mysqli`. Something like this:

```
/*
 * Thousands of calls like this in my codebase:
 */
db_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . db_input($id));

/*
 * Single file with these functions:
 */
function db_query($query)
{
     global $dblink;
     return mysqli_query($dblink, $query);
}

function db_input($param)
{
    //various checks on input, if/else (redacted)
    global $dblink;
    $param = mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $param);
    return $param;
}
```

I am considering switching to using PDO, because PDO has named parameters & prepared statements and I like those.  (`mysqli` also has prepared statements but not named parameters and I'm partial to that).  How I will convert is another question, but my concern is ... Let's say I successfully convert my codebase into using PDO.  What are my long term consequences?

**Option 1**

I can continue to use my own proprietary methods like `db_query` that now use PDO inside of them, like this:

```
function db_query($query)
{
     return $db->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

*This will keep my code intact, and keep my actual DB native PDO methods in a single file*

**Option 2**

I can start to use PDO directly from my code, in all its glory, something like

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, ... );
$sth->execute(array(':id' => 1));
$record = $sth->fetchAll();
```

I will no longer use `db_query`.

*This will make my code peppered in PDO statements everywhere and much harder to rewrite should I want to switch away from PDO later*

**Goal/Spirit of the question**:  I am interested in long-term effects, side-effects, maintenance of the codebase.  I am essentially asking .. do I keep wrapping PDO/mysqli into my proprietary `db_query` calls, or do I start using PDO/mysqli directly in my code?

To fully use PDO prepared statements and full power of PDO, it seems I best use Option 2, but that means PDO will be "out of the bag of confinement of my proprietary redirect calls (`db_query()`)." and PDO methods will spill out into my codebase and no longer be confined into one single "DB methods" file.  I am concerned that doing so will become an inconvenience later on in my code should I for example decide that I want to go back to `myqsli` or switch to `Doctrine` or what have you.

My alternative is to keep using `db_query` but beef it up to allow for named parameters, to essentially write my own wrapper over PDO.   (this will be Option 1 + provisions to write a wrapper over PDO so I can keep using `db_query()` + named parameters + PDO behind the scenes).  But will I open myself up to a world of trouble (extra work, little gain, bugs inherent to writing my own wrapper ).  Although this options means I will have my own proprietary layer that will in theory stay intact, while I can change mysqli to PDO, and back, behind the scenes.

**Suggestion by Robert**

Option 1 + amend the wrapper to accept parameters

```
//to call:
db_query(
    'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id', 
    array(':id' => 1)
);

//update to accept params
function db_query($sql, $params = null)
{
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, ... );
    $sth->execute($params);
    $record = $sth->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you convert your existing wrappers to PDO, and then use raw PDO in the application for those few cases where you require the additional power?

Comment: so say I convert my file that houses `mysqli` native calls, to `PDO` calls and keep using `db_query()` + `db_input()` for most cases.  My plight is that most of my SQL statements use some kind of a parameter and I wanted to get away from using non-prepared statements like I have been using.  I guess it begs another question: is my using `db_query()` + `db_input()` (aka non-prepared statement), just as good as using `prepared statement` + `parameters` that are offered by PDO/mysqli

Comment: You can't make the inner part of your wrappers use prepared statements?  What about a generic array parameter; does PHP support that?

Comment: I probably can.  That'd be Option 1 + update my wrapper to accept parameters.  Then just pass them to PDO

Comment: @Robert I've updated my question to include what I understood you've suggested

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: You mentioned Doctrine.  The Doctrine Database Access Layer (http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) is a thin wrapper over pdo and provides a number of convenient utility functions including allowing the use of arrays for IN(?) statements and a very nice query builder.  Since you are already going through the pain of moving to pdo, you might consider moving directly to Doctrine.

Comment: There is still a SQL injection in your code: `1OR1=1` shows all dB entries. You should really continue the upgrade to prepared statements

Comment: @Cerad:  Thanks.  One qualm I have with DBAL is that it takes away my direct free-range customization control over SQL and complicates it by introducing proprietary syntax.  It becomes a midde-man between me and SQL.  I have been using Doctrine in some parts of the project and while I see some benefits, I am beginning to become disenchanted by the time and effort it takes me to bend DBAL to my will when I want to just write the SQL and move onto other things.  This is why I debate whether I wish to stay with mysqli but add prepared statements or try PDO with same purpose.

Comment: You may be confusing Doctrine's DBAL with Doctrine's ORM(Object Relational Manager).  The ORM has it's own query language and introduces a bunch of stuff for dealing with objects.  The DBAL is just a thin wrapper over PDO and gives you some helper functions like inserting records using an array.  The sql is the same.  But either way works.

Comment: Thanks.  I indeed had it confused, because I looked at DBAL and saw QueryBuilder and associated it with Doctrine.